# Error while automating youtube video using selenium webdriver in java

Tags: youtube, automation

Getting the below error while trying to automate the video in youtube using selenium webdriver in java.

I have copied the code to automate from the below link.

> https://seleniumonlinetrainingexpert.wordpress.com/2012/12/03/how-to-automate-youtube-using-selenium-webdriver/

Below is the error I am getting

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: document.movie_player is undefined
>   Command duration or timeout: 23 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
>   System info: host: 'HYDPCM99232L', ip: '10.1.1.3', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
>   Session ID: a573f5f2-29c4-4b62-a5f2-54e44a762547
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
>   Capabilities [{platform=WINDOWS, acceptSslCerts=true, javascriptEnabled=true, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=true, browserName=firefox, handlesAlerts=true, nativeEvents=false, webStorageEnabled=true, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=true, takesScreenshot=true, version=40.0.2}]
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:204)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:156)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:605)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.executeScript(RemoteWebDriver.java:514)
>       at FlexWebDriver.callFlashObject(FlexWebDriver.java:23)
>       at Youtube.main(Youtube.java:17)
>   Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: document.movie_player is undefined
>   Build info: version: '2.46.0', revision: '87c69e2', time: '2015-06-04 16:17:10'
>   System info: host: 'HYDPCM99232L', ip: '10.1.1.3', os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_79'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown
>       at .anonymous(.....youtube link...)

Am I missing anything to install/configure to automate youtube videos?
This is driving me crazy since 2 days.

Comment: is this problem solved?

Comment: yes...i resolved the problem...thanks

Comment: how did you do it? please answer your question.

Comment: I had fixed the problem and the code looks like

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem and the code looks like

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
    import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
    import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
    import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;

    public class YouTube {

        @Test
        public void test1() throws InterruptedException {
            //Initialising the firefox driver
            FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            //navigating to the below url 
            driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxoXvn2l2gA");

            Thread.sleep(5000L);

            WebElement video = driver.findElement(By.tagName("video"));
            JavascriptExecutor js = driver;

             //pausing the video
            js.executeScript("arguments[0].pause();", video);

            Thread.sleep(5000L);

//playing the video         
js.executeScript("arguments[0].play();", video);
            Thread.sleep(5000L);

//muting the video          
js.executeScript("arguments[0].mute();", video);
            Thread.sleep(5000L);

//unmuting the video            
js.executeScript("arguments[0].unMute();", video);
            Thread.sleep(5000L);

//Dragging the video            
js.executeScript("arguments[0].currentTime = 600;", video);
            Thread.sleep(5000L);

            js.executeScript("alert(arguments[0].readyState);", video);

            driver.quit();

        }

    }
```

Comment: Hmm... could you [edit your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/38557775/edit) to add comments that throroughly explain what does the code do? Doing so would make the answer more useful to future visitors (and more likely to get upvotes).